# Word to describe a flower fading out from existence

Tags: antonyms

For a flower to "bloom" means that it comes into existence. What would be a word that means it is fading out from existence?

> blooming flowers

I got these antonyms from google search, none seems to match.

- sterile
- barren
- declining
- fading
- unfruitful

Comment: Can you describe the what a flower going through the process which is "opposite of blooming" looks like? What do you want this word to mean? Are you looking for simply *wilt* or *wither*?

Comment: bloom like coming into existence as a flower. opposite, fading out from existence

Comment: Then yes, you want *fade* (which is idiomatic), or *wilt*, or *wither* (stronger, usually due to some external force), or some idiom like *the bloom is off the rose*. You can use these words as jumping-off points in a thesaurus search.

Comment: You might find this article on a specific Japanese concept inform your search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_no_aware

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Wilt**

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wilt

*to become weak and begin to bend towards the ground, or (of a person) to become weaker, tired, or less confident:*

> Cut flowers will soon wilt without water.

Answer (score 1):

One good verb for this is **wither**:

> (of plants etc) to (cause to) fade, dry up, or decay. *The plants withered because they had no water*; *The sun has withered my plants.*
>   <sub>*Kernerman English Multilingual Dictionary* via [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wither)</sub>

Here are some examples of this in use:

- [Life of a Rose Flower (Blooming to Withering)-Timelapse Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITkfI9PacN4)
- [Withering Flower Time Lapse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uF9W6YNYyJ8)

Answer (score 0):

Mushrooms deliquesce (change from solid to liquid).  Flowers defloresce.  At least they should.  I heard it used once, but can't find it in the dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Since I can't comment, I will suggest these:

- retreat
- crumple

Examples:

> The orchid *retreated* in the harsh cold.
>
> The wizard was dismayed to discover that his summoned flower quickly *crumpled* in the arid sands of Hammerfell.

Comment: Since we consider plants to be sessile, *retreat* is inapt. *Crumple* includes the sense of being crushed, which isn't necessary for faded flowers. Do you have examples of these two words used in the context of flowers no longer in bloom?

Comment: @deadrat I was more going for antonyms of "bloom", with "bloom" in the form of a verb. Retreat may be used metaphorically to describe the behavior of flower going through a reverse process of blooming, instead of just being unbloomed. I used crumple more to compare an unblooming flower to crumpling paper, being that both of those objects are thin and relatively fragile, and the action of crumpling to describe how a flower may fold or curl up.

Comment: I understand all that. You "may" use whatever you want in metaphoric and descriptive speech. I just don't think these words *are* used in that way. I could be convinced by evidence. Do you have any?

Comment: @deadrat The fact of whether or not those words have been used in that context before is irrelevant to how fitting they are as antonyms to "bloom", or how cohesively they would fit into a sentence about flowers reversing the process of blooming. If they haven't been used in that way before than the author has obtained a little extra originality.

Comment: I gather that these examples are your own creations, making the answer to my question, no. By the way, I am not the downvoter.